# Netbeans alter syntax highlight for log lines

Tags: java, netbeans, syntax

Is there a way to modify Netbeans syntax highlighting in java with a regular expression or plugin or something?

I'd really like to "grey" all the *Logger.getLogger...* of filter them. It would make my life easier.